# Stripe 3D Secure when Saving Cards for future payments

Tags: stripe-payments, 3d-secure

Is it possible to use 3D Secure when saving cards for future payments?

From Stripe's docs, https://stripe.com/docs/sources/three-d-secure. This seems to be the way to do it.

However according to the documentation, it's no longer recommended and to use PaymentIntents instead:

> Use of this API is no longer recommended. If you wish to use 3D Secure we strongly encourage you to adopt PaymentIntents, our new payments API.

So with that, is there a way to use PaymentIntents (to utilize 3D secure) to just save a card without making a payment immediately?

Comment: I'm not sure your question makes sense. A Payment Intent is explicitly an attempt to collect payment, and 3D Secure only happens when you make a payment. If you're just saving the card without making a payment, you would create a source using stripe.js's `stripe.createSource` like in Step 1 of your link, and [save it to a customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/sources/customers#attaching-a-source-to-a-new-customer-object). Then, later, if you want to charge the card you can create a Payment Intent. https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/usage#using-a-saved-source

Comment: Our use case is that we want to save the customer's cards for future charges and these future charges will be done automatically in our server's background so we can't get 3d secure info from our customers at that future time. So we want to utilize 3D secure authentication during saving of cards. I've asked stripe support about this and they said 3D secure for saving cards without making a payment is currently not supported.

Comment: Hi @len I'm trying to achieve the same thing, have you find a way to do this with payment intent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [the `SetupIntent` API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/setup_intents), which are basically `PaymentIntent` with a null amount (same workflow).

Answer (score 5):

just to let you know, I have contacted the Stripe support as I get the same concern as you, here the answer:

> [...] PaymentIntents currently does not support creating sources without also creating a charge thereafter. It's also not possible to integrate 3DSecure with the current method of saving credit cards unfortunately.
>
> PaymentIntents is a fairly new Stripe product and we're still working out the kinks and deciding what functionality we'll support down the line. Saving sources is definitely high on our priority list and there'll be more information on this update in the future.

I tried to get more info about their roadmap to know if the feature will be released by september, but the support could not give me the info.

*Edit*:
stripe has improve its documentation and now explaining how to implement what you want while respecting the SCA https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/saving-cards#saving-card-without-payment and https://stripe.com/docs/payments/cards/charging-saved-cards

Comment: Please have a look at the other answer here.. I'm also trying to figure out the same thing.. :/

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to use 3D Secure when saving cards for future payments?

What I do using `PaymentIntents` is to create a customer and then make the payment:

```
customer = stripe.Customer.create(

payment = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(customer=customer_id, ....
```

In payment you have the card type `payment['charges']['data'][0]['payment_method_details']['card']['brand']` and the last 4 digits of the card `payment['charges']['data'][0]['payment_method_details']['card']['last4']`

You can store locally the `customer_id`, the card type and the last 4 digits to show them to that customer next time.
To make another payment you only need to use `stripe.PaymentIntent.create()` with the `customer.id` you saved the first time.
If the customer wants to use another card just do

```
customer = stripe.Customer.modify(
                customer_id,
                source=token_id
           )
```

`token_id` comes from stripe.js in your frontend

Comment: From what I understood, this answer contradicts the other one which just got a reply from Stripe's support that this was not possible :) It seems logical that you should be able to store a card's "metadata" with the Customer, and the PaymentIntent can be created later from this and only then it triggers the 3D-Secure 2.0 step. But does it actually work? :)

Comment: I think you didn't get the use case: what author (and everyone involved in this topic) wants to achieve is: Saving a customer card with 3D secure enabled one day, then charge the card later. This is the case when you want to build a custom subscription system and because the provided subscription system does not fit your needs.
Currently it seems PaymentIntents does not support this use case.
We are all aware that you can create a PaymentIntents, that will charge "immediately" the card, and save this card for other later payments

Comment: When you create the customer you are sending a token_id from stripe.js after the user write his card number, so the customer you create in Stripe has the card information. After this you have the ID of the customer so you are able to create a PaymentIntent with the charge you want to make. For me is working in test mode, the only problem I have now is that I don't receive the message from the iframe when 3DSecure is needed, but the payments are in the stripe dashboard :)

Comment: What I don't know if author is talking about saving cards locally or in stripe. I think at the beginning applications saved cards locally and from time ago, we dont save and don't want to save cards locally. I think that the answer from support is talking about saving cards locally, PaymentIntents is intended to not save cards locally but on their systems.

Answer (score 0):

Set `setup_future_usage='off_session'` when creating a payment intent.

```
stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
  amount=1099,
  currency='usd',
  setup_future_usage='off_session',
)
```

These stripe docs show how to save a card in a way that should allow future "off_session" payments for cards which use 3D Secure.

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents#future-usage

[image]